# Удаление локальных файлов docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, macos

Есть база данных postgres, которая была импортирована внутри докер контейнера. Сейчас необходимо удалить этот файл на локальном компьютере(или все что связано с этой бд). Используется macOS

Comment: если запускали локально, то ищите куда ссылается `echo $PGDATA` и удалите данные

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, отображает пустую строку

Comment: тогда я не понимаю вопрос.  что за локальные файлы? как запускали postgres на хосте?  что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, в ubuntu эти файлы находятся в /var/lib/docker/, если я не ошибаюсь. А в macos эти файлы должны лежать в ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/, но по этому пути у меня только файл Docker.raw

Answer (score 1):

1. Смотрите все доступные контейнеры `docker container ls -a`
2. Останавливаете нужный контейнер `docker container stop [container_id]`
3. Удаляете нужный контейнер `docker container rm [container_id]`
4. Смотрите все образы `docker image ls`
5. Удаляете нужный образ `docker image rm [container_id]`

Также прилагаю ссылку на статью в которой вы можете найти как удалить `network`,`volume`,`resource`.
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/remove-docker-images-containers-networks-volumes